# Is saying "He was well thought of" ending a sentence with a preposition?

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions, sentence

If not, is there any other way to say this? (I'm looking for synonyms, not rewordings such as "Others thought well of him.")

Comment: It's better than "Of well he was thought"!

Answer (score 1):

Ending a sentence with a preposition is completely fine in English.
Just google this:

sentences ending with prepositions

You can find lots of examples for yourself. Actually it will be awkward to not end with a preposition in some sentences. Here are a few examples: [Sentences ending with prepositions](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/ending-sentences-with-prepositions)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rewrite it without a preposition at the end then the following is perfectly grammatical and has the same meaning.

*He was thought of well.*